# Searching inside scala 2.10 ASTs

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-2.10, parse-tree

What's the best way to recursively search for an element in scala 2.10 ASTs?

The trees might be a result of `power.trees(code)` or `mirror.mkToolBox().parseExpr(code)`
**Edit**. In 2.10.0-RC1 `parseExpr` has been renamed to `parse`.

The concrete use-case that I have is extracting the code of a method from a given class/object code by method name,
but I assume that the question would be more relevant for others if formulated in a more generic way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you should have a look at https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L606, especially at the classes Traverser, Transformer and the methods for substitution (`Tree.substituteSymbols`, `Tree.substituteTypes` or `Tree.substituteThis`). If you want to extract a method from a tree, you can use a `Traverser` and override the `traverse` method. In the traverse method, you check whether the node matches the method you want. If so, you are done. If not, you call `super.traverse`.

Comment: The linked code is quite obsolete in comparison with trunk. Here are the correct links: 1) tree AST classes: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/reflect/base/Trees.scala, 2) transformers and traversers: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L606

Comment: Here's example of a transformer: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/46d57d47e81c8794a9a3594e080576788cc92324/src/compiler/scala/reflect/reify/phases/Reshape.scala (the code would definitely use a cleanup, but it's too nice of an example to ignore it). Note the `super.transform` and `copyAttrs` parts.

Comment: Also `TreeSubstituter` is not exposed in the API. Use `Tree.substituteSymbols`, `Tree.substituteTypes` or `Tree.substituteThis` where appropriate (or write your own transformer).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have updated my answer accordingly.